# Adding dynamic async component by name in variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

De idea is not to program the name, but to pass the name as a property.

So i can have a base vue component and i tell what vue component to load in there dynamicly by giving name and location.
Which works perfect when i type the string (set the name) but not when i put the name in a string then it says module not found.

so if I `import('./yyy.vue')` it works but if. but if I `import(var_that_is_the_name)` it says not found. i think it has something to do with laravel mix or stringparsing.

```
   <template>
    <div class="xxx" ref="xxx">
            <component :is="dynamicComponent"></component>
            <div class="right">
                right {{ this.DvueLocation }}
            </div>
    </div>
   </template>
   <script>

   import { defineAsyncComponent } from '@vue/runtime-core'

   export default {
    name: 'xxx',
    components: {

    },
    props: {
        DvueLocation: {
            type: String,
            default: "./yyy.vue",
        },
        DvueName: {
             type: String,
             default: "yyy"
        }
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            isMounted: false,
        }

    },
    computed: {
        dynamicComponent() {
            console.log(this.DvueLocation);
            return defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./yyy.vue'))
       return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(this.DvueLocation))
        }

    },
}
</script>
```

the yyy.vue is a simple component that prints yyy.

first line works, second with not cold not add // for it and save.
i tried putting "'" + around it en lots more

while its exactly the same if i type it.
both the string printed and on console of browser gives the right value

Comment: Please, fix the formatting, the question is hard to read. Not limiting to a specific set of components is not a good idea overall. Consider explaining your case, it could be XY problem. If you need to switch between several comps, their import paths should preferably be explicitly listed

Comment: Thank you Estus, was my first post and had some trouble selecting all as code and learning how to edit. Not an XY problem do, and i figured part of it out when i made this sniplet. the solutions works, and all i want works if i type it and not use a variable. Anyway if i use return defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./' + this.DvueName)) so it has something to do with the . or / in location

Comment: As an added comment what it is for, but i stripped it down to the part i was having a small challenge with.  I building a Grid Layout, where i define de properties in a mariadb database and then recursive build a grid with yes or no navbar, contents left right menu's etc.

Comment: This will automatically add every single component in your project to the bundle and prevent tree shaking, chunking, etc from working. If you're able to narrow it down to several components and list them explicitly, it will work much better

Comment: Besides I use lazy loading and prefetch, and you only seen 1 inch of my code (which i narrowed down to prevent an XY problem) and was more a bug then a fault in coding as far as i can see. Since i had the right values but it was not parsed right. It is parsed the correct way,  when i split the string into 2 strings, and then combine them to the original, so i not change the string is more a bug.  Anyway I wanted to learn this. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Besides this is just 1 component so very simple, why i want to use this besides it is like great and they invented it in veu3 for it and they awesome. What i can do with it 1 of the things is make a very simple and small veu-router. which changes the content on main window with loading the base veujs. simple easy to type the name. Then after mounted en de user can see the page in ms, i can initialize bij var name or array in the background all content that would possible on the grid. en when the user clicks something instantly change the contents of the grid.

Comment: so i can do it for top grid, left grid, right grid , main area etc. or i can simply make 1 compoment, tell it what component to start with by a variable, and give an array of components to import after mounted and the users see the website and tell it if its on the top grid, left grid right grid. etc. which is veujs you make a component you can use again by changing props.

Comment: You can do it the way you consider necessary, but purely dynamic import is unwise for the reasons I listed. Also wrong paths won't be detected at compilation time. You won't find this approach being used without a good justification.

Comment: Estus thanks for your comments, but since veujs calls it an great nieuw future, i gonna go with them and figure it out somehow. So if besides telling me i should not do it, you have a solution for the dot parsing bug, i am much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with string parsing.

```
return defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./' + this.DvueName))
```

This works for me now!

Comment: I found some more and its the dot and veu-router, not found how to fix it do all i found did not work https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-does-not-catch-routes-with-a-dot/14717 i will return to the problem later hope somebody finds some solution. thanks for review all

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.